# How Can i import plugin option wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

hey guys i'm trying to import my plugin option into wordpress with php
but i can't find any tutorial or describe about this section

i have this example:

my option name:

> get_option('meow');

what i have in this option are

```
'cats'=> '2',
'food' => array('tona','fish'),
```

so how can i use

> update_option

to import this values?
i tried this way but it's not working

```
update_option('meow', 'cats','5');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `get_option('meow', 'cats','5');` to check or import data. `update_option` just updates the value of an option that was already added.

To tell you more we need more information how you stored the option in an array. I didnt even use it in this way before.

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/).